# Use Excel pivot table as data source for another Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table in excel that is using a raw table as its data source.  This pivot table is doing a bunch of grouping and summing of rows.

I'd like to now use the result of this new pivot table as the data source for a new pivot table which will further modify this data.

Is this possible with excel?  I suppose you could call it 'nested pivot tables'

Answer (score 24):

- Make your first pivot table.
- Select the first top left cell.
- Create a range name using offset:

  `OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$3,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$3:$3))`
- Make your second pivot with your range name as source of data using F3.

If you change number of rows or columns from your first pivot, your second pivot will be updated after refreshing your second pivot.

Comment: Using offset and counta in this way is clever. Filed away for future use

Comment: I get (translated) a datasource is invalid error.  I'm using excel 365

Comment: What is  GFGDT ?

Comment: Global Fundamental Geospatial Data Themes for Africa is all I could find, and rather lengthy representations, if not badly phrased, of each letter. What is the meaning of GFGDT in astronumerology? https://voticle.com/meaning-of/gfgdt/gfgdt-means-gfgdt-stands-for but alas, I digress.

Comment: I'm a little late here, but the OP's username is GFGDT. I imagine they added it to the end of their answer as a sort of signature.

Comment: Removed GFGDT from the end of the answer.

Answer (score 18):

In a new sheet (where you want to create a new pivot table) press the key combination (Alt+D+P). In the list of data source options choose "Microsoft Excel list of database". Click Next and select the pivot table that you want to use as a source (select starting with the actual headers of the fields). I assume that this range is rather static and if you refresh the source pivot and it changes it's size you would have to re-size the range as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, when I click next, I don't see all the pivot in the file excel. There is something that I can do for view all the pivots?

Comment: What command does the Windows shortcut Alt+D+P refer to?  I'm using MacOS and thus don't have an Alt key.  If I knew I could find way of invoking it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your end goal is to show Distinct (unique) values inside your original Pivot table.

For example you could have data set with
OrderNumber, OrderDate, OrderItem, orderQty

First pivot table will show you OrderDate and sum of OrderQty **and you probably want to see Count of unique orders in the same Pivot**.
You woudln't be able to do so within standard pivot table

If you want to do it, you would need Office 2016 (or perhaps pover Pivot might work). 
In office 2016 select your data > Insert > Pivot Table > **choose tick "Add this  data to the Data Model"**

After that, you would be able to select grouping method as Distinct (Count)

Comment: This should be the correct answer (assuming the end goal is distinct counts)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you can change the pivot table content and paste as values.
But if you want to change the values dynamically the easiest way I found is
Go To `Insert->create pivot table`
Now in the dialog box in the input data field select the cells of your previous pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the pivot to values first before you can do that:

- Remove the subtotals
- Repeat the row items
- Copy / Paste values
- Insert a new pivot table

Answer (score 0):

As @nutsch implies, Excel won't do what you need directly, so you have to copy your data from the pivot table to somewhere else first. Rather than using copy and then paste values, however, a better way for many purposes is to create some hidden columns or a whole hidden sheet that copies values using simple formulae. The copy-paste approach isn't very useful when the original pivot table gets refreshed.

For instance, if Sheet1 contains the original pivot table, then:

- Create Sheet2 and put `=Sheet1!A1` into Sheet2!A1
- Copy that formula around as many cells in Sheet2 as required to match the size of the original pivot table.
- Assuming that the original pivot table could change size whenever it is refreshed, you could copy the formula in Sheet2 to cover the whole of the potential area the original pivot table could ever take. That will put lots of zeros in cells where the original cells are currently empty, but you could avoid that by using the formula `=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1)` instead.
- Create your new pivot table based on a range within Sheet2, then hide Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I got around this in a slightly different way - I had a pivot table querying an SQL server source and I was using the timeline slicer to restrict the results to a date range - I then wanted to summarise the pivot results in another table.

I selected the 'source' pivot table and created a named range called 'SourcePivotData'.

Create your summary pivot tables using the named range as a source.

In the worksheet events for the source pivot table, I put the following code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

'Update the address of the named range
ThisWorkbook.Names("SourcePivotData").RefersTo = "='" & Target.TableRange1.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & Target.TableRange1.AddressLocal

'Refresh any pivot tables that use this as a source
Dim pt As PivotTable
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each pt In Sheet2.PivotTables
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
Next pt
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Works nicely for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

here is how I've done this before.

1. put a dummy column "X" off to the right of your source pivot table.
2. click in that cell and start your pivot table.
3. once the dialogue box pops up you can edit the data range to include your pivot table.
4. this may require you to Refresh the source table  first and then refresh your secondary pivot table...or do refresh all twice

Answer (score -1):

I love the offset option -- i had to create a range called that first and did a -3 instead of a -1.  Then used that new range for my new pivot table.  Now when the first pivot changes, the second will pickup the new rows (or less rows)...

Comment: As a new user without enough rep to comment, there is a temptation to add comments as answers. However, it's not really encouraged on the site and this commenty answer will probably draw downvotes. I suggest you refrain from this and wait until you get enough rep to comment. Or you could edit this to be a full answer, indicating exactly where and how this offset is defined and why it solves the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30317036)