# How to create pivot table of a pivot table OR add a pivot table into Power Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I created a dashboard sourcing the data through Pivot tables generated with a Data model.
The challenge I have at the moment is to get a slicer that shows the actual values of the pivot table (not a filter but the values).

Since I know a slicer doesn't do that, so I would like to create a pivot table of a pivot table to overcome this issue.

What I already tried:

I created a pivot table of another pivot table by selecting the first pivot table when creating the second one. However, I have two issues here: 1) not sure if the second pt will update dynamically and 2) the data source of the second pivot table is not in the Data model so I can't connect slicers to other pivot tables or pivot graphs (this is a requirement).

Any alternatives to be able to create a pivot table of a pivot table which will be included in the Data model and will adjust dynamically?

Comment: I tried all the solutions on this link 
[use excel pivot table as data source for another pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333070/use-excel-pivot-table-as-data-source-for-another-pivot-table) to fix this issue but none worked for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.